# Using Visual Studio Code to develop Unity3D projects in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have KDE neon (based on Ubuntu 18.04). I have installed the latest Linux version of Unity3D [from this link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2).

I need a C# script editor to start developing C# projects. How do I setup Visual Studio Code to work with Unity3D projects? I need it to auto-complete code and underline compilation errors.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Please note that the following instructions contain commands that are specific for 18.04. Please check the sources if you have a different version of Ubuntu or Linux.*

---

## 1. Install the C# extension for Visual Studio Code

[image: C# Extension Screenshot]

---

## 2. Install the "Debugger for Unity" extension for Visual Studio Code

[image: Debugger for Unity Extension Screenshot]

## 3. Install the latest version of "Mono"

Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework sponsored by Microsoft. Instructions for a repository installation:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-devel
```

[(Source)](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin). It also has instructions for 16.04 and 14.04.

## 4. Install dotnet

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

[(Source)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial). It also has instructions for 16.04, 14.04 and others.

## 5. Open your project's folder with Visual Studio Code

[image: Screen photo, opening project folder with Visual Studio Code]

## 6. Set the "Unity Debugger" in Visual Studio Code

Select the debug view on the left and click the cogwheel.

[image: Screenshot 1 from Github]

In the drop down list select “Unity Debugger”. If you do not have Unity Debugger in the list, then you already have a .vscode/Launch.json file in your project that you must delete first.

[image: Screenshot 2 from Github]

You will now have a .vscode/Launch.json file in your Unity project folder and can select which Unity target you wish to debug.

[image: Screenshot 3 from Github]

[(Source)](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/vscode-unity-debug).

Comment: Fantastic answer. Very in-depth and detailed. If I had to use VSC I'd be completely lost trying to set it up myself! Thankfully I have a license for Visual Studio proper, so I can use what Unity magically installs for me.

Comment: @Draco18s the reason to prefer VSC while developing often is the fact that it opens up way faster than VS does.

Comment: @derHugo Nothing wrong with that. :) I just remember a time when VS wasn't distributed with Unity and I tried to set it up (after having gotten frustrated at MonoDevelop) and was unable.

Comment: For anyone who is having problems with intellisense, auto complete after installing VScode. Here are some suggestions:
 - Be sure of having dotNet.
 - Select VScode from Unity->Preferences->External Tools->External Script Editor->Browse
 - Some suggest to change "External Script Editor Args", which is just below "External Script Editor" tab, to $File$ but instead of that I clicked "Reset Argument". And It did work for me.
 - Install correct extensions in VScode. You can find them here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity
 
I hope these may help.

Comment: Very fantastic answer. I suggest also this link: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin